# Why is Xcode not recognizing indexOfObjectIdenticalTo in swift array?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, nsarray

I'm trying to translate some Objective-C code:

```
NSArray *containers = [layoutManager textContainers];
NSUInteger lastUsedContainerIndex = [containers indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:textContainer];
```

to Swift:

```
let textContainers = layoutManager.textContainers
let lastUsedContainerIndex = textContainers.indexOfObjectIdentical(to: textContainers)
```

Where layoutManager is of type NSLayoutManager. I'm getting this error on the last line of the Swift code:

> Value of type '[NSTextContainer]' has no member
>   'indexOfObjectIdenticalTo'

Not understanding this. I've searched the docs for Swift and NSArray has `indexOfObjectIdenticalTo` yet it's not showing up in Xcode's autocomplete and is giving me this error. Am new to Swift so wondering what am I missing here?

Comment: In Swift, this is imported as [`NSArray.indexOfObjectIdentical(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1410847-indexofobjectidentical), so this would be spelt: `textContainers.indexOfObjectIdentical(to: textContainers)`. But in Swift, this would be more conventionally written as: `textContainers.firstIndex(where: { $0 === textContainers })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, this is imported as [`Foundation.NSArray.indexOfObjectIdentical(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1410847-indexofobjectidentical). This isn't available on `Swift.Array`, so you would first have to bridge your `Array` to `NSArray`, so this would be spelt:

```
let textContainers = layoutManager.textContainers
let lastUsedContainerIndex = NSArray(textContainers).indexOfObjectIdentical(to: textContainer)
```

But in Swift, this would be more conventionally written as:

```
let textContainers = layoutManager.textContainers
let lastUsedContainerIndex = textContainers.firstIndex(where: { $0 === textContainer })
```

Comment: Thanks so much, was getting confused between the difference between NSArray and Swift array, thought they were one of the same (maybe implicit in Swift) when I saw how the docs had the Swift translation.

Comment: @NSMoron TL;DR: Swift's native array type is `Array`. `NSArray` is part of `Foundation`, and is available for use in Swift in order to support interoperability with old ObjC APIs. Most ObjC APIs (like UIKit) have been annotated to bridge into Swift using `Array`, but not all.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now, appreciate you taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSTextContainer]` is not an instance of `NSArray`. You could try to cast your array to `NSArray`.